# What are those SATA connectors?

Tags: ssd, sata, cable

I have bought a Dell Poweredge T440. I'd like to use embedded SATA for one of my SSD but i can't figure out what is this SATA connector on the motherboard:

[image]

https://qrl.dell.com/Files/en-us/Html/Manuals/T440/System%20board%20jumpers%20and%20connectors=GUID-461E8EC8-B6DC-4D7C-93EF-5D6E6D37D8D3=1=en-us=.html

On this link, it shows:

**(6)** SATA connector for ODD/TBU which looks like a regular SATA connector (Can I use this one for a SSD?)

**(3)** and **(13)** which are SATA_A and SATA_B but what kind of cables do i need to use those SATA ports? (I can't find it on Google)

Comment: can you find a better picture? the link you sent tells me nothing.

Comment: SATA ports need... SATA cables of course.

Comment: Did you *try* a standard SATA cable before posting this question? If not, start there. If so, please explain more clearly what issue you're facing.

Comment: Off course otherwise i wouldn't have post this question !! This is not a standard SATA port and i wonder how to connect HDD on this... For the moment i have used the ODD SATA port to plug my SSD but i don't know if i will get the same speed than with the 2 strange connectors...

Comment: @JohnnyVegas : here is a better quality picture http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/fr/fr/frdhs1/poweredge-t440/pet440_ism_pub/connecteurs-et-cavaliers-de-la-carte-syst%C3%A8me?guid=guid-461e8ec8-b6dc-4d7c-93ef-5d6e6d37d8d3&lang=fr-fr

Comment: @psusi : i know but this is described as a SATA connector and it's not, what kind of connector is this ?? Maybe SAS but even SAS connector don't look like that :(

Answer (score 1):

There are a few types of connectors and they all appear to be pin compatible Sadly, none of them are named "A" or "B". (Blame DELL)

I would have to guess they are either:

- Slimline
- Micro (uSATA)

According to the manual this server supports a slimline ODD and a SAS tape drive so I would suspect one is a slimline port and one is a SAS port.

> The Dell EMC PowerEdge T440 system supports:
>
> one optional slim SATA DVD-ROM drive or DVD +/-RW drive
>
> internal tape drives LTO5, LTO6, LTO7 and external SAS drives.

SOURCE: https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/19/poweredge-t440/pet440_ism_pub/optical-drive-and-tape-drive?guid=guid-72f9ac85-5c7d-4426-8422-9e2e71b0c5cf&lang=en-us

Answer (score 0):

"TBU" means tape backup unit. If you search YouTube for "Dell TBU" you will find instructional videos they posted. "ODD" means optical disc drive. Both should work just fine (although I guess there's a chance they're a slower SATA interface).

Answer (score 0):

Those SATA ports are to be used for non hotswapable drive installs, you have to use a special cable like found here, https://www.aliexpress.com/i/4000120709658.html, to use them. It's not a regular SATA port for HDs and ODDs, etc.